# Knockout.js Mapping and adding large dataset to ko.observableArray

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

There are many examples of adding large datasets to a ko.observableArray using the underlying array such as this:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.pushAll = function(valuesToPush) {
var underlyingArray = this();
this.valueWillMutate();
ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, valuesToPush);
this.valueHasMutated();
return this;  //optional
};
```

The problem with doing it this way is I lose my observables.  When I use chrome and pause in debugger, I get the values in my array rather than the function c() which is the observable wrap.  I have to also observe many of these variables.

I found what does work is the following:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
vm.POs = ko.mapping.fromJS(model.POs);
```

The problem is that this is slow.  How do I use the underlying array to add but then add the observable wrap to each variable without performance issues?

Here is some more code:

```
var vm = {
    POs: ko.observableArray([]),

    headersWithAccounting: ko.observableArray([
        {header_name: "DATE CREATED", property: "DATE_CREATED", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "DATE ISSUED", property: "DATE_ISSUED", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "USER CREATED", property: "NAME_USER", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "PO NUMBER", property: "NO_PO", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "ORDER STATUS", property: "NAME_STATUS", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "VENDOR", property: "NAME_VENDOR", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "TOTAL COST", property: "COST_TOTAL", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "CTU", property: "ID_CTU", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "ACCOUNTING CODE", property: "ACCOUNTING_CODE_NAME", state: ko.observable('')},
        {header_name: "CLOSE ORDER", property: "ACCOUNTING", state: ko.observable('')}
    ])
};

function PO() {
var self = this;

self.ID_ORDER = ko.observable();
self.DATE_CREATED = ko.observable();
self.DATE_ISSUED = ko.observable();
self.NAME_STATUS = ko.observable();
self.NAME_VENDOR = ko.observable();
self.NAME_USER = ko.observable();
self.COST_TOTAL = ko.observable();
self.ACCOUNTING_CODE_NAME = ko.observable();
self.ACCOUNTING_CODE_ID = ko.observable();
self.NO_PO = ko.observable();
self.SHOWDETAILS = ko.observable(0);
self.ID_TYPE = ko.observable(0);
self.DESCRIPTION = ko.observable('');
self.FILES = ko.observableArray();
self.POParts = ko.observableArray();
self.ACCOUNTING = ko.observable(0);
self.ID_CTU = ko.observable(0);
self.ACCOUNTING.subscribe(function(val) {
    if (vm.avoidCloseOrder() == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AccountingCloseOrder", "Report")',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                orderId: self.ID_ORDER()
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                if (msg != 'Good') {
                    window.location.href = msg;
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error closing order, please try again");
            }
        });
    }
});
self.ACCOUNTING_CODE_ID.subscribe(function(val) {
    if (vm.avoidCloseOrder() == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AccountingCodeChange", "Report")',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                orderId: self.ID_ORDER(),
                accountingCodeId: self.ACCOUNTING_CODE_ID()
            },
            success: function(msg) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error closing order, please try again");
            }
        });
     }
  });
}

function POPart() {
    var self = this;

    self.CATEGORY = ko.observable();
    self.SUBCATEGORY = ko.observable();
    self.DESCRIPTION = ko.observable();
    self.PARTNO = ko.observable();
    self.QTY_ORDERED = ko.observable();
    self.QTY_RECEIVED = ko.observable();
    self.COST = ko.observable();
}

function FILE() {
    var self = this;

    self.LOCATION = ko.observable();
}
```

Now the issue is in the razor code with the knockout bindings:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div data-bind="foreach:POs">
            <table class="table-responsive">
                <thead data-bind="if: $index() == 0 || ($index() > 0 && vm.POs()[$index()-1].SHOWDETAILS() == 1)">
                    <tr data-bind="foreach:vm.headersWithAccounting">
                        <th>
                            <span data-bind="click:$root.sortPOs.bind(property), text:header_name" style="cursor:pointer"></span><i data-bind="css: state"></i>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="clickabletbody">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="click:$parent.showDetailsFor">
                            <div data-bind="text:DATE_CREATED"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="click:$parent.showDetailsFor">
                            <div data-bind="text:DATE_ISSUED"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="click:$parent.showDetailsFor">
                            <div data-bind="text:NAME_USER"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="click:$parent.showDetailsFor">
                            <div data-bind="text:NO_PO"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="click:$parent.showDetailsFor">
                            <div data-bind="text:NAME_STATUS"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="click:$parent.showDetailsFor">
                            <div data-bind="text:NAME_VENDOR"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="click:$parent.showDetailsFor">
                            <div data-bind="text:COST_TOTAL"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="click:$parent.showDetailsFor">
                            <div data-bind="text:ID_CTU"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddlVendor", new SelectList(Model.ACCOUNTING_CODE_SELECTLIST, "Value", "Text"), "--Select Accounting Code--", new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value:ACCOUNTING_CODE_ID" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" style="height:30px; width: 30px;" data-bind="checked:ACCOUNTING, enable:(NAME_STATUS() == 'ACCOUNTING' || NAME_STATUS() == 'CLOSED')" />  //PROBLEM RIGHT HERE!!!!
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table data-bind="if:SHOWDETAILS, fadeVisible:SHOWDETAILS" style="background-color:antiquewhite" class="table-responsive">
                <!-- ko if:(ID_TYPE() == 2 || ID_TYPE() == 3) -->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            DESCRIPTION
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div data-bind="text:DESCRIPTION"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if:(ID_TYPE() == 1) -->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            CATEGORY
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            SUBCATEGORY
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            DESCRIPTION
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            PART NO
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            QTY ORDERED
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            QTY RECEIVED
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            COST
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach:POParts">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div data-bind="text:CATEGORY"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div data-bind="text:SUBCATEGORY"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div data-bind="text:DESCRIPTION"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div data-bind="text:PARTNO"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div data-bind="text:QTY_ORDERED"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div data-bind="text:QTY_RECEIVED"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div data-bind="text:COST"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </table>
            <table data-bind="if:SHOWDETAILS, fadeVisible:SHOWDETAILS" style="background-color:antiquewhite" class="table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Files
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach:FILES">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a data-bind="attr: {href: LOCATION, target: '_blank'}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Download File</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div data-bind="if:SHOWDETAILS"><hr /></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is with the checkbox, chrome console says error: 
knockout-3.4.0.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "enable: function (){return (NAME_STATUS() =='ACCOUNTING'|| NAME_STATUS() =='CLOSED') }"
Message: NAME_STATUS is not a function

This is because in the value it is no longer a function with knockout bindings, it is simply a value, therefore it is not a function and this error is correct.  I am losing this because using the underlying array pushes only the javascript values and is not mapping the observable function.

It is taking roughly 10 seconds for 200 entries to map currently using observables, which is pretty ridiculous if you ask me. What will happen when I have 1000+.  Even if I only load 50 of them starting out and use ajax to gather the rest behind the scenes, every time I get more data, it will lag the page for a few seconds until it loads them all.  Not sure how to go about fixing this.

Edit:

I just had an AHA moment and fixed the losing binding problem.  It is taking roughly 4 seconds now for 232 entries. Would still like to get it faster but heres what I changed.

```
function PO(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.ID_ORDER = ko.observable(data.ID_ORDER);
    self.DATE_CREATED = ko.observable(data.DATE_CREATED);
    self.DATE_ISSUED = ko.observable(data.DATE_ISSUED);
    self.NAME_STATUS = ko.observable(data.NAME_STATUS);
    self.NAME_VENDOR = ko.observable(data.NAME_VENDOR);
    self.NAME_USER = ko.observable(data.NAME_USER);
    self.COST_TOTAL = ko.observable(data.COST_TOTAL);
    self.ACCOUNTING_CODE_NAME = ko.observable(data.ACCOUNTING_CODE_NAME);
    self.ACCOUNTING_CODE_ID = ko.observable(data.ACCOUNTING_CODE_ID);
    self.NO_PO = ko.observable(data.NO_PO);
    self.SHOWDETAILS = ko.observable(0);
    self.ID_TYPE = ko.observable(data.ID_TYPE);
    self.DESCRIPTION = ko.observable(data.DESCRIPTION);

    self.FILES = ko.observableArray();

    if (data.FILES != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.FILES.length; i++) {
            self.FILES.push(new FILE(data.FILES[i]));
        }
    }

    self.POParts = ko.observableArray();

    if (data.POParts != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.POParts.length; i++) {
            self.POParts.push(new POPart(data.POParts[i]));
        }
    }

    self.ACCOUNTING = ko.observable(data.ACCOUNTING);

    self.ID_CTU = ko.observable(data.ID_CTU);

    self.ACCOUNTING.subscribe(function(val) {
        if (vm.avoidCloseOrder() == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("AccountingCloseOrder", "Report")',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    orderId: self.ID_ORDER()
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg != 'Good') {
                        window.location.href = msg;
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("Error closing order, please try again");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    self.ACCOUNTING_CODE_ID.subscribe(function(val) {
        if (vm.avoidCloseOrder() == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("AccountingCodeChange", "Report")',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    orderId: self.ID_ORDER(),
                    accountingCodeId: self.ACCOUNTING_CODE_ID()
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("Error closing order, please try again");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function POPart(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.CATEGORY = ko.observable(data.CATEGORY);
    self.SUBCATEGORY = ko.observable(data.SUBCATEGORY);
    self.DESCRIPTION = ko.observable(data.DESCRIPTION);
    self.PARTNO = ko.observable(data.PARTNO);
    self.QTY_ORDERED = ko.observable(data.QTY_ORDERED);
    self.QTY_RECEIVED = ko.observable(data.QTY_RECEIVED);
    self.COST = ko.observable(data.COST);
}

function FILE(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.LOCATION = ko.observable(data.LOCATION);
}
```

And the push function:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.pushAll = function(valuesToPush)
{
    var underlyingArray = this();
    this.valueWillMutate();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(valuesToPush, function(item) {
        underlyingArray.push(new PO(item));
    });
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return this;
}
```

Any ideas to make this faster than 4 seconds?

Comment: Impossible for us to tell, currently. Performance issues are context specific, and we're missing your context. Could you try to create a representative but minimal repro? AFAICT you could strip out the server side bit (and its tags), further simplifying things so we can more easily help.

Comment: Why are you generating a pushAll function? Why not `self.observableArray().concat(self.newObservableArray())` or `self.observableArray().concat(self.newArray)` if the second array is not an observable

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get what you mean by "I loose my bindings". It's maybe a debugger artefact (which shows you the value of the observable).

I could also be a "this" issue.

I get this snippet which is working (and you can use the click binding while array is populated)

```js
var elementVM = (function () {
    function elementVM(message) {
        this.myText = ko.observable(message);
    }
    elementVM.prototype.changeText = function () {
        this.myText(this.myText() + " changed");
    };
  
    return elementVM;
}());

var myVM = (function() {
  var getText = function(count) {
    return "My Text " + (count);
  };
  
  var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray([new elementVM(getText(0))]);
  
  return function() {
    this.myArray = myObservableArray;
    myVM.prototype.populate = function() {
      myObservableArray.valueWillMutate();
      
      for(var i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i) 
      {
        myObservableArray().push(new elementVM("My Text " + i));
      }
      
      myObservableArray.valueHasMutated();
    };
  };
}());

var vm = new myVM();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
  var start = new Date();
  vm.populate();
  var stop = new Date();
  document.getElementById("pushAll").innerHTML = "pushallTiming: " + (stop - start);
}, 1000);
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#pushAll {
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="pushAll"></div>
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', foreach: myArray }"></ul>
 
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
    <li data-bind="text: myText, click: changeText"></li>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual copying to the array takes less than 1 sec.  It is the valueHasMutated() function which is taking a few seconds ands thats just part of KO.  I'm glad its not taking long to copy the data into the array.  I will try to paginate only 50 entries which should help the DOM load faster.  Thanks for everybody who responded.